# Command line - show surrounding context lines in a file around known exact line number

Tags: awk, sed, command-line-interface

How to output N(e.g. 2) lines surrounding a specific known line number(e.g. 5) in a file?

```sh
cat >/tmp/file <<EOL
foo

bar

baz

qux

quux
EOL

# some command
```

Expected output:

```
bar

baz

qux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the line and number of lines in advance and thus you are able to compute the number of the first line and number of the last line you might use simple GNU `sed` command, for example

```
sed -n '3,7p' file.txt
```

will output 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th line of `file.txt`.

If you wish to change the line number then I would use GNU `AWK` following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=5}NR==n-2,NR==n+2' file.txt
```

Explanation: I set n to 5 then I use [Range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) to select lines from `n-2`th line (inclusive) to `n+2`th line (inclusive), no action is provided which is equivalent of giving `{print}`.

Answer (score 1):

Robustly, portably, and efficiently printing a context (same number of lines either side of a target line):

```
$ awk -v tgt=5 -v ctx=2 '
    BEGIN{beg=tgt-(ctx=="" ? bef : ctx); end=tgt+(ctx=="" ? aft : ctx)}
    NR==beg{f=1} f; NR==end{exit}
' file
bar

baz

qux
```

or different numbers of lines before and after the target line:

```
$ awk -v tgt=5 -v bef=2 -v aft=4 '
    BEGIN{beg=tgt-(ctx=="" ? bef : ctx); end=tgt+(ctx=="" ? aft : ctx)}
    NR==beg{f=1} f; NR==end{exit}
' file
bar

baz

qux

quux
```

In particular for efficiency note:

1. The math to calculate the begin/end line numbers is done once in the BEGIN section rather than recalculated every time a line is read, and
2. The `NR==end{exit}` instead of `NR==end{f=0}` or similar so awk doesn't waste time unnecessarily reading the rest of the input file after the desired lines have been printed.

Answer (score 0):

Without line number prefixes:

```sh
awk -v nr=5 'FNR>=nr-2 && FNR<=nr+3{ print $0 }' /tmp/file
```

```
bar

baz

qux
```

---

With line number prefixes:

```sh
awk -v nr=5 'FNR>=nr-2 && FNR<=nr+3{ print FNR":"$0 }' /tmp/file
```

```
3:bar
4:
5:baz
6:
7:qux
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
sed -n $((5-2)),$((5+2))p file
```

Which fetches the range +/- 2 lines from line 5 of file.

Another way is to use grep:

```
greg -FC2 $(sed -n 5p file) file
```

Find line 5 in file using sed and then grep 2 lines of context either side of that line.